# Windows 8 generates less heat than Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, cpu, temperature

I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and Windows 8 Professional on my laptop.

When running Windows 7 on my laptop, the CPU core temperature usually ranges from 42°C to 47°C. However, when I run Windows 8, the CPU core temperature usually ranges from 36°C to 41°C with the exact same hardware. I am using a custom power plan with the same settings in each OS as well.

I used [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) to measure the temperatures, and I was running the exact same programs I normally run under each system. The temperatures were tested about two hours after a cold boot. The machine sat overnight powered off and with the battery fully charged before each test.

What might be causing this? How can I get Windows 7 to run at a lower temperature. Is there something I need to do differently?

Comment: Have you monitored CPU usage over an extended period of time for both OSes? Any significant observations?

Comment: While I can't find any definitive sources as of yet, I believe they re-vamped the internal task scheduler making the OS more efficient.  A few benchmarks cited [almost 5% performance increases](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/features/windows_8_Review?page=3%2C4) in the same programs running on Win8 vs. Win7, which would explain the lower temperatures as well (simply more efficient!).

Comment: in the technet forums, some users have the different experience. They have overheating issues in Windows 8: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproperf/thread/fe19f08a-6c37-4b8d-bda2-082ef154be6b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows 8 has better energy and CPU management, particularly at idle.  Windows 8 strives to get your processor cores back to idle as soon as possible in order to lower energy consumption and better battery life on laptops.  Since more CPU usage means more heat, you're likely seeing the benefits of these improvements.

http://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-57321356-75/windows-8-plans-to-better-manage-your-battery-life/

As for getting these nice energy-saving features into Windows 7, I guess it depends on whether they're planning this as a hotfix or an inclusion in a future Service Pack.